# ReportViewer com lista de uma tabela e informações de outra tabela

Tags: c#, relatório, reportviewer

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma tabela `AVALIAÇÃO` e outra `PACIENTE`. Preciso gerar toda a relação de avaliações de um determinado paciente. Já tenho a query no meu datatable que faz isso, porém, não sei como exibir as informações das duas tabelas, já que de um lado tenho todas as informações de paciente e do outro posso ter vários registros de avaliações, ou seja, terei que usar um TABLE para avaliação no report e outro `TABLE` ou `TEXTBOX` para exibir os dados do paciente.

Query do datatable de AVALIACAO:

```
SELECT avaliacao.*, paciente.* FROM avaliacao a INNER JOIN paciente p ON a.idpaciente = p.id WHERE p.id = @p
```

Comment: você poderia fazer dois selects, um para trazer somente os dados do paciente e o outro para trazer as avaliações desse paciente, nesse caso você teria dois Data Sources.

Comment: Como eu adiciono dois data sources no meu reportviewer? @GeiltonXavier

Comment: veja esse link - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826772/using-multiple-datasets-in-rdlc